# Why UITextField is ignoring "\n" character on device, but not in storyboard?

Tags: swift

When adding a UITextField in storyboard, in the 'text' field, you can add new line by doing CTRL+ENTER and the field will increase its height automatically.

I tried to assign a string where I replaced from ", " to "\n", but the end result is my string with 'spaces' instead of "\n".

This is what I see, but I know it is "\n" because I tried to replace the "\n" to ", " and it worked.

Any idea why I have that behavior? I know I could use a UITextView, but for this case, I need a UITextField.

Thanks

Comment: A text field is not meant to have multiple lines

Comment: @LeoDabus, I understand, but why it is working on Storyboard then?

Comment: @David is there something that you need from text fields? Text views can usually substitute them

Comment: @aheze, I have my solution with textview, but wanted to avoid to have code that is already handled by a class that does validation only with textfield. Also, I wanted to understand why the storyboard is letting me add new line to my textfield and programmatically, it does not work.